# Node.js socket.io emit array

Tags: массивы, node.js, socket.io

У меня есть массив координат:

```
/**
*  Стандартное расположение шашек 
*/
Checkers.prototype.coord = function() {
    
    // координаты шашек 
    var checkers_coords = new Array();

    checkers_coords['white'] = ["5.0","5.2","5.4","5.6",
                                "6.1","6.3","6.5","6.7",
                                "7.0","7.2","7.4","7.6"];
            
    checkers_coords['black'] = ["0.1","0.3","0.5","0.7",
                                "1.0","1.2","1.4","1.6",
                                "2.1","2.3","2.5","2.7"];
                                
    return checkers_coords;
}
```

Я пытаюсь послать этот массив клиенту:

```
socket.emit('start',game.coord())
```

Однако он приходит пустой, хотя на сервере распечатывается как нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ?

Comment: А клиенту как отправляете?

Comment: socket.emit('start',game.coord())

Comment: проблема решена:

        var checkers_coords = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ из комментария:

проблема решена: `var checkers_coords = {};`